# VBA - Pull changing exchange rates from Oanda

Tags: excel, vba, rates

I'm doing a project and need help getting started.

Essentially what I am doing is pulling data with changing parameters every single day and need the exchange rate for the average period.

Example: Today is June 10th. I need the Period Average from June 1st to June 9th of various exchange rates.

The difficult part is that every day, I need to update the period range and change the exchange rates being viewed. So tomorrow, the 11th, I will need the PA from the 1st to the 10th.

Anyone have any ideas on how to get started?

Answer (score 0):

Arrange the data how you want it and then use the Excel macro recorder to record the actions that you want to take. That will give you a good starting point. You can then examine the code, work out what it is doing and change it as required.